# CGridView Pager Issue

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

There are 16 records in my MySQL table. I have put a query to get distinct records by date and it returns 10 records. But on the view page, in grid view, Summary shows:

> Displaying 1-10 of 16 results.

But it should show

> Displaying 1-10 of 10 results.

But the records that are being shown are 10. Why?

My code is :

```
<?php
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'DISTINCT(`call_date`)';
$criteria->order = 'call_date DESC'; 
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('modelName', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in the past too when using distinct. You can "fix" it by passing in the correct number of items.

To do that, add [totalItemCount](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider#totalItemCount-detail) to your $dataProvider like this:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('modelName', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'totalItemCount' => count(modelName::model()->findAll($criteria)),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
```

`modelName::model()->count($criteria)` doesn't work for this.

Comment: This is really bad advice, you don't want to use it if you have more than tens of records. `count(modelName::model()->findAll($criteria))` will load all records and then count them - it is extremely inefficient and memory-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should adjust [`CActiveDataProvider::$countCriteria`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider#countCriteria-detail) to count only unique `call_date`:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('modelName', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'countCriteria'=>array(
        'select' => 'COUNT(DISTINCT `call_date`)',
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
))
```